# return index of item in list according to another list, python

Tags: python, list

I need to find list items in another list.

for example:

```
a = ['s','u','v']
b = ['u','s','a']
```

I would like to get as a result a boolean array (or list), that indicates for each item in a, if this item exists in b.
so for that example i would get:

```
[1,1,0]
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = ['s', 'u', 'v']
>>> b = ['u', 's', 'a']
>>> [i in b for i in a]
[True, True, False]
>>> [int(i in b) for i in a]
[1, 1, 0]
```

The most important operation is `i in b`, which returns whether the element `i` exists in the collection `b`. For information on list comprehensions, read [here](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Comprehensions.html).

This also shows that `True == 1` and `False == 0`. `bool` is actually a subclass of `int`. If they don't *need* to be `int`s, keeping them as `True` and `False` will be faster.

This would be much more efficient if `b` were a `set`, which you may want to do depending on the size of `b`. This can just be done with `set(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

This works, it's a list comprehension:

```
# a = ['s','u','v']
# b = ['u','s','a']

[(0,1)[e in b] for e in a]

# [1, 1, 0] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using condition in list comprehension you could obtain what you want:

```
a = ['s','u','v']
b = ['u','s','a']
[1 if i in b else 0 for i in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want zeros and ones instead of boolean values:

```
>>> [1 if i in b else 0 for i in a]
[1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
a = ['s','u','v']
b = ['u','s','a']

print ([int(t) for t in [x in b for x in a]])
```

Output;

```
[1, 1, 0]
>>>
```

Used list comprehensions and turned boolean values to integer witn `int()`since `True == 1` and `False == 0`.

Comment: Please explain how your solution works and why it is better then other solutions

Comment: @Koopakiller I made it one-liner. I'll explain now